# Understanding tcpdump output on a linux router 

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tcpdump

My router has an `atm0` interface and a VLAN (`atm0.1`) interface, `atm0.1` has the WAN IP address.

When using `tcpdump -i atm0`, the packets captured are only outgoing packet (LAN to WAN).

```
05:34:19.504895 IP 10.110.51.83 > 74.125.71.104: ICMP echo request, id 768, seq 29184, length 40
05:34:20.506885 IP 10.110.51.83 > 74.125.71.104: ICMP echo request, id 768, seq 29440, length 40
05:34:21.507868 IP 10.110.51.83 > 74.125.71.104: ICMP echo request, id 768, seq 29696, length 40
```

When using `tcpdump -i atm0.1`, the packets captured include both outgoing packets and incoming packets.

```
05:36:33.517705 IP 10.110.51.83 > 74.125.71.104: ICMP echo request, id 768, seq 30208, length 40
05:36:33.827969 IP 74.125.71.104 > 10.110.51.83: ICMP echo reply, id 768, seq 30208, length 40
05:36:34.519715 IP 10.110.51.83 > 74.125.71.104: ICMP echo request, id 768, seq 30464, length 40
05:36:34.685847 IP 74.125.71.104 > 10.110.51.83: ICMP echo reply, id 768, seq 30464, length 40
05:36:35.521643 IP 10.110.51.83 > 74.125.71.104: ICMP echo request, id 768, seq 30720, length 40
05:36:35.679061 IP 74.125.71.104 > 10.110.51.83: ICMP echo reply, id 768, seq 30720, length 40
```

Why?

linux version is 2.6.30, atm driver are from broadcom.

Comment: @Eric, I feel sorry for anyone still stuck with an [ATM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode)-attached host.  What did you do to the technology gods to deserve this?

Comment: @Mike: What's specific to unix about this question? It looks like a generic IP networking question to me.

Comment: @Gilles, his question was tagged `linux-kernel` on StackOverflow; the issue is why tcpdump on `atm0` only shows outgoing PDUs instead of seeing the bidirectional traffic when he sniffs on the VC (`atm0.1`).  From a pure IP networking perspective, he should be seeing bidirectional traffic when sniffing `atm0`.  My suspicion is that this has something to do with how `libpcap` reads from the driver, but that's not something I have expertise in

Comment: @Mike: Ah, ok. @Eric: What OS is your router running (if Linux, what distribution, e.g. OpenWRT, CentOS, etc, and what version)? What kernel version (`uname -srv`)?

Comment: @eric, In addtion to Gilles' request... what specific NIC and driver are you using? As root execute `lsmod` and `lspci | grep -i atm`, and add this to your post

Answer (score 1):

This is not uncommon. The point where libpcap sets up a hook to intercept network traffic may not be always the right one to capture all the traffic.
After all, virtual interfaces are just a set of functions - usually optimized for speed - not to create a perfect replica of a physical interface.
Asymmetric traffic capture may happen with vlans, tun/tap interfaces and bridges.
Always try capturing in promiscuous mode or normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the path of the traffic is:

```
application -> atm0 -> atm0.1 -> destination
destination -> atm0.1 -> application
```

Comment: @cnicutar, your answer makes no sense from an ATM perspective.  Sniffing `atm0` should see `atm0.1` traffic just like my ability to see traffic on `vlan12@eth0`  by sniffing on `eth0` (and I do this almost every day)